# sphere collider collid shoot player ship?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, I made some progress with the look towards me I'm able to get the enemy ship to follow the player and the laser guns as well could use some guidance how to get the laser to kill the player ship and prompt  the  lose and the 'R' for restart messages Aanty insight how to go about it is welcomed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class EnemyManagement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject deathFX;
    [SerializeField] Transform parent;
    // The target marker.
    [SerializeField] Transform target;

    // Angular speed in radians per sec.
    [SerializeField] float speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        AddSphereCollider();
    }

    private void AddSphereCollider()
    {
        Collider sphereCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
        sphereCollider.isTrigger = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;

        // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDir, step, 0.0f);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, newDir, Color.red);

        // Move our position a step closer to the target.
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. You added a collider. Great. Where's the code that says "on collide, invoke `FireEnemyGunsActive()`"?

Comment: Hi Draco,  I made some changes since last you read still doesn't work I will create an on collide invoke and get back :/

Comment: `OnPartilceCollision` is not correct. Also, now you're missing any code to fire guns.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Hint: is the `player` a particle? No? Then why are you checking for the player inside a *particle* collision method?

Comment: Okay Thank you,  I will work on this later this week after I get my final assignment for school done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a radius for collision detection.

`sphereCollider.radius = 10.0f;`

Comment: I changed my code and added some comments please read again will look into your suggestion. Thank you